# Using POST to get data instead of GET request

Tags: java, rest

I see in few legacy applications, POST request is used to return data to the client. Input data is provided in Form data. 
Ideally to get data we should be using GET request.

What are the possible reasons to use POST instead of GET to get data ?

If its for security reasons, why we have GET in the first place ?
If input data is large, probably we may have to choose POST.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

GET is for requests that fetch data without altering the essential state of the data source, while POST is for requests that alter the state of the data source.
POST also hides the data from the server log files.